# rails client_side_validations and select tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, client-side-validation

The gem client_side_validations doesn`t validate select tag with no item selected. Maybe need to pass some params in model or .erb file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is trying to do validate presence. Try validating **numericality / greater than > 0**.

Comment: A little hackish IMO.  Is there a technical obstacle to making this work without having to validate this way?

Comment: If you are validating select tag with related models, use `validates :model_name_id` instead of `validates :model_name` (in model file) eg. `validates :client_id` instead of `validates :client`.